# Nested array - ambiguous

Tags: swift

When trying to create the array below, I get the following error:

> type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Is an array such as this possible in Swift? If yes, how is it declared?

```
var jobArray = [
    ["Dog Walker", "Job Description", ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], "7"],
    ["Babysitter", "Job Description", ["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], "15"],
    ["Leaves Raker", "Job Description", ["Sunday", ""], "10"]
]
```

Comment: Is `Friday` supposed to be unquoted?  What type of array are you *trying* to declare?

Comment: Your code should work. You need to provide the context where you are using it

Comment: I can not reproduce this error in Swift playground.  More context will be necessary.

Comment: This is being done in the playground. I get that exact error.

Comment: Update your Xcode or add var jobArray:  [AnyObject] = whatever. Do you have any code in the line above this one?

Comment: I'm running 6.3.2. I'll update to 6.4 Beta and see if that works.

Comment: no code in the line above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m guessing in your playground you aren’t importing `Foundation` or anything similar:

```
// uncommenting the below line fixes the problem
// import Foundation

// with it commented out, 
var jobArray = [
    ["Dog Walker", "Job Description", ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], "7"],
    ["Babysitter", "Job Description", ["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], "15"],
    ["Leaves Raker", "Job Description", ["Sunday", ""], "10"]
]
```

Without it you get *two* errors:

> ```
> error: '_' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'
> ["Dog Walker", "Job Description", ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], "7"],
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
> ```

The first one is much more important.  The second one is an artifact of Swift going up and going home.

Why?  Because what would the type of `[jobArray]` be?  There is no type in the Swift standard library that would fit this definition – you’d need a `[[Something]]` where `Something` conformed to both `StringLiteralConvertible` (for `"Dog Walker"`) and `ArrayLiteralConvertible` (for `["Sunday", ""]`).  And there ain’t one.

Sadly, very sadly IMHO, such things *are* defined within `Foundation`.  Which is why it compiles when you add the import.

I would strongly suggest, instead of defining this array like this, that you implement a simple `struct`:

```
struct Job {
    let jobDescription: String
    let days: [String]  // or even an enum for the days of the week
    let hourlyPay: Double
}

var jobArray = [
    Job(jobDescription: "Dog Walker", days:  ["Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday"], hourlyPay: 7),
    Job(jobDescription: "Babysitter", days:  ["Tuesday", "Wednesday"], hourlyPay: 15),
    // etc
]
```

Comment: That was it. I had the Foundation in there when I first created the playground, then it was removed at some point. Thanks much

Comment: How would I access individual elements using the struct in the array? For instance instead of using [0][1][0] to get "Monday"

Comment: `jobArray[0].days[0]`