# Programmatic Paginated Navigation in Swift / UI Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, pagination, navigation

I'm a senior Ruby developer, and just getting into Swift and iPhone development, but can't seem to make heads or tails of where to begin with answering my own question. My apologies ahead of time if I sound extremely newb!

My goal is to take a set of data ( in Ruby, it would be a hash or JSON ), and form `x` views from it. For example, the data might be :

```
my_page_info = {
{
  title: "Page 1",
  content: "Blah blah blah",
  additional_info: "Some more blah"
},
{
  title: "Page 2",
  content: "Blah blah blah",
  additional_info: "Some more blah"
},
{
  title: "Page 3",
  content: "Blah blah blah",
  additional_info: "Some more blah"
}  
}
```

*Side Question.. What would be the best way to write that kind of information in Swift? Assuming it wouldn't be in JSON..*

Then I'd assume, it would be proper architecture to use just one view in the UI Builder that would represent all available data in this array. Where `my_page_info` would populate 3 different labels defined as `@IBOutlet`'s arranged in my UI View Controller, and then interpolate the values.

Lastly, I wanted to have a back and forward button that would allow me to navigate these items. I looked *everywhere* for such a system icon, but it seems like it doesn't exist. At least not within the UI Builder. I imagine it can only be done programmatically, and then I'd have to import my own images to represent those buttons.

Would anyone know any part of my question, or direct me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Airspeed Velocity's answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30406668/nested-array-ambiguous), you see that a struct would be the way to go for your data:

```
struct Page {
    let title: String
    let content: String
    let additionalInfo: String
}

var myPageInfo = [
    Page(title: "Page 1", content: "Blah blah blah", additionalInfo: "some more blah"),
    Page(title: "Page 2", content: "Blah blah blah", additionalInfo: "some more blah"),
    Page(title: "Page 3", content: "Blah blah blah", additionalInfo: "some more blah"),
]
```

Note the removal of the underscores from variable names.

Then, I think you would want a tableview, where you set up a single prototype cell in Interface Builder with fields for each corresponding field in your data.

**Edit**: you probably just want the title in the cell and you would pass the other info through a segue (see below) to the page where everything is laid out all nice.

Then your cellForRowAtIndexPath method would look like:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("pageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PageCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = "myPageInfo[indexPath.row].title"
    cell.contentLabel.text = "myPageInfo[indexPath.row].content"
    cell.additionalInfoLabel.text = "myPageInfo[indexPath.row].additionalInfo"

    return cell
}
```

Your prepareForSegue method in the tableViewController would pass the values for the data selected to the ViewController that you set up to display the info.

I'm not sure what you're looking for in the last part, but if you use a navigationController, you automatically get a Back button (which in your case would go back to the tableViewController)

Comment: Thanks so much @Shades . That answers a lot of my questions.  Havn't seen the back button yet, but maybe it'll pop up by itself when I write all of this code..

Comment: Embed your tablewViewController in a navigationController and watch the magic